# Delphi TGridPanel - dynamically hide some rows

Tags: delphi, layout, tgridpanel

I have grid panel 16 x 4 like this one:

[image]

Sometimes i want to hide some rows and to move bottom rows up. When I set component visible property to false the layout is not updated:

[image]

Nevertheless the row size type is set to auto:

[image]

Why the component don't set row height to zero when there is nothing to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Why the component don't set row height to zero when there is nothing to display ?***

Because the row is considered as empty only if there are no components in all columns in that row, not if they're visible or not. So the same returns the [`IsRowEmpty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomGridPanel.IsRowEmpty) method. To workaround this, you'd need to be notified by the cell component about its visibility change. When this notification is generated, you can check the row just like the [`IsRowEmpty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomGridPanel.IsRowEmpty) method does, except you'll check if the controls are visible, not if they're assigned. Based on the result of such method, you can then set the size of the [`Value`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCellItem.Value) to 0 to hide the row.

With a help of interposed class, the method for checking if all controls in a row or column are visible, you might write something like this. Those methods return True, when all existing controls in a certain row or column are visible, False otherwise:

```
uses
  ExtCtrls, Consts;

type
  TGridPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TGridPanel)
  public
    function IsColContentVisible(ACol: Integer): Boolean;
    function IsRowContentVisible(ARow: Integer): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

function TGridPanel.IsColContentVisible(ACol: Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (ACol > -1) and (ACol < ColumnCollection.Count) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to ColumnCollection.Count -1 do
    begin
      Control := ControlCollection.Controls[I, ACol];
      if Assigned(Control) and not Control.Visible then
        Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    raise EGridPanelException.CreateFmt(sInvalidColumnIndex, [ACol]);
end;

function TGridPanel.IsRowContentVisible(ARow: Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (ARow > -1) and (ARow < RowCollection.Count) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to ColumnCollection.Count -1 do
    begin
      Control := ControlCollection.Controls[I, ARow];
      if Assigned(Control) and not Control.Visible then
        Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    raise EGridPanelException.CreateFmt(sInvalidRowIndex, [ARow]);
end;
```

And the usage shown for the first row:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // after you update visibility of controls in the first row...
  // if any of the controls in the first row is not visible, change the 
  // row's height to 0, what makes it hidden, otherwise set certain height
  if not GridPanel1.IsRowContentVisible(0) then
    GridPanel1.RowCollection[0].Value := 0
  else
    GridPanel1.RowCollection[0].Value := 50;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a hacky solution ... keeping the Autosizing

```
Procedure ShowHideControlFromGrid(C:TControl);
begin
  if C.Parent = nil then
    begin
      c.Parent := TWinControl(c.Tag)
    end
  else
    begin
    c.Tag := NativeInt(C.Parent);
    c.Parent := nil;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin   // e.g. Call
 ShowHideControlFromGrid(Edit5);
 ShowHideControlFromGrid(Edit6);
 ShowHideControlFromGrid(Edit7);
 ShowHideControlFromGrid(Label1);
end;
```